# Create Tags: Vertical, Vertical-Datum, Height, Height-System, Gravity

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Advancements in understanding the Earth's geoid already are producing purely gavimetric geoid models critical to making accurate vertical transformations and overall elevation refinements for any given vertical datum. `vertical`, `vertical-datum`, `height`, `height-system` and `gravity` are common terms to search and should be added to the tags list.

Comment: Why create tags when you can already search for them as strings?

Comment: Tags are created by posters (and occasionally by high-reputation answerers) as they are needed to describe questions that are actually asked.  We do not maintain the tags list as an independent dictionary of the subject.

Answer (score 5):

I think the [geodesy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geodesy) and [datum](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datum) tags are enough to cover this. The fact that any user with at least 300 reputation (see [Privileges](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) in the [Help Center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help)) can [create tags](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) and that these haven't been created yet suggests that other tags have been sufficient. Not every word in the English language relating to GIS needs to be a tag, just enough to help organize things.

> **When should I create new tags?**
>
> Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

Comment: Time will tell - that's the answer I suppose you're saying - and that makes sense. And Poly's rhetorical question really does too, really. For example, user1205577's question from 6 weeks ago (found because it was tagged with geoid) [Height of the geoid in ECEF coordinates](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70243/height-of-the-geoid-in-ecef-coordinates) is answered completely with the string search in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Height+of+the+geoid+in+ECEF+coordinates&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Comment: I am wondering whether you are using a browser or mobile client because the browser client makes SE searches like [**this**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=geoid+ECEF) easy while only Google searches seem to be available from the mobile client.

Comment: I understand whubwer's and blah238's answers, but i do not understand "Poly's rhetorical question" (about strings). In fact i flagged it as unconstructive. Am i stupid? What has google or strings got to do with the purpose or function of tags? Thanks.